# How to create a Rotation Matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a rotation matrix in tensorflow where all parts of it are tensors.

What I have:

```
def rotate(tf, points, theta):
    rotation_matrix = [[tf.cos(theta), -tf.sin(theta)],
                       [tf.sin(theta), tf.cos(theta)]]
    return tf.matmul(points, rotation_matrix)
```

But this says that `rotation_matrix` is a list of tensors instead of a tensor itself.  `theta` is also a tensor object that is passed in at run time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with two operations:

```
def rotate(tf, points, theta):
    rotation_matrix = tf.pack([tf.cos(theta),
                              -tf.sin(theta),  
                               tf.sin(theta),
                               tf.cos(theta)])
    rotation_matrix = tf.reshape(rotation_matrix, (2,2))
    return tf.matmul(points, rotation_matrix)
```

Comment: I was considering this but then forgot it.  I think this is more eloquent then what I'm currently doing.

Comment: `tf.pack` has been renamed to `tf.stack`, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7550

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question of 'How to build a Rotation Matrix', the following is cleaner than requiring a multiple `pack` (`stack`) calls:

```
tf.stack([(tf.cos(angle), -tf.sin(angle)), (tf.sin(angle), tf.cos(angle))], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

An Option I found that works is to use pack but if there is a better way please post an answer:

```
def rotate(tf, points, theta):
    top = tf.pack([tf.cos(theta), -tf.sin(theta)])
    bottom = tf.pack([tf.sin(theta), tf.cos(theta)])
    rotation_matrix = tf.pack([top, bottom])
    return tf.matmul(points, rotation_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Tensorflow Graphics](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics), which has some nice helper functions regarding representation of 2D and 3D rotations.

```
import tensorflow_graphics.geometry.transformation as tfgt
tfgt.rotation_matrix_2d.from_euler([0.1])

# <tf.Tensor: id=48, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[ 0.9950042 , -0.09983342],
#        [ 0.09983342,  0.9950042 ]], dtype=float32)>
```